# Exporting Mahout model output as Weka input

Tags: hadoop, weka, mahout, decision-tree

I would like to use the output model of a Mahout decision tree training process as the input model for a Weka based classifier.

As the training of a complex decision tree that is based on millions of training records is almost impractical for a single node Weka classifier, I would like to use Mahout to build the model, using for example [Random Forest Partial Implementation](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/partial-implementation.html).

While the algorithm above can be problematic while training, it is rather simple to use it for prediction with Weka on a single machine.

On Mahout [wiki site](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/data-formats.html) it is stated that the data formats for import include Weka ARFF format, but not for export.

Is it possible to use some of the existing implementations in **Mahout to train** models that will be used in **production with a simple Weka** based system?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do what you're asking: .arff is a data format, as are all of the other options in the import/export menus. The classifiers that Weka can save/load are, in fact, Weka's java `Classifier` objects written to a file using Java's `Serializable` interface. They're not so much portable trees as they are Java objects that last longer than the JVMs which create them. Thus, to do what you want, either Mahout or Weka would have to be able to produce/read each other's code, and that's not something I can find any documentation of.

My experience is that with several million training records (consisting of ~45 numeric features/columns each), Weka's Random Forest implementation using the default options is very fast (operating in seconds on a single 2.26GHz core), so it may not be necessary to bother with Mahout. Your data set may well have different results, though.

Comment: You are probably right regarding Random Forest in Weka, but its memory requirements are not trivial, and it's much worse with other algorithms. I really liked the ease of training with Mahout, but dislike the slow prediction time.

Comment: True. Have you seen this: [link](https://code.google.com/p/fast-random-forest/wiki/SpeedAndMemoryUse) ? You can use it in weka, and the sharts at the link suggest that this implementation of RF is easier on CPU time and memory. I haven't tested it myself, and I can't find anything verifying its accuracy, but you could easily do a small test with some data in this and in default RF implementation, and see if your results were comparable.

Comment: Nice link, but it only shows to prove the problematic point of Weka on Java and Single machine. It works as long as you have relatively small data. The promise of Mahout is to allow larger scale problems to be solved. How can we combine these horse and elephant to work together in building a real life large scale application.

Comment: @Guy, this link does go part way to bridging your that gap: it will utilize multiple cores and reduce both memory and CPU use. However, I don't think that it is possible for Mahout to produce a model Weka will understand. Weka uses models that are essentially instances of its own source code (`serialized objects`). Do you run into problems when you try using either this or the original weka implementation of RF? Mahout, I have read, includes some non-hadoop implementations of algorithms. Perhaps this would give you the classification you want while still using hadoop to build the classifier?